# What are the benefits and drawbacks of using Zeuterin or a product like it for neutering a dog?

Tags: dogs, desexing

What are the benefits and drawbacks of using Zeuterin or a product like it for neutering a dog? Zeutrin is a product that chemically castrates a male dog via an injection directly to the center of the testes by a vet. It avoids surgery and leaves some hormone production in place.

I have talked to several people that are interested in it and I hear that it has been used outside of the US for some time. Does anyone have experience with it? Are there any good places to read about it that are not just from the company producing it? Are there any similar products out there?

Answer (score 3):

So, Zeuterin (or Esterisol) is a relatively new means of neutering male dogs in the United States (much longer outside) and there hasn't been a lot of long-term information yet established about it. However, there are studies and the information has been summarized in a [comparison paper](http://www.acc-d.org/ACCD%20docs/2008%20AJVR%20Levy%20Study.pdf) by Drs. Levy and Crawford. Some possible side effects from that information include:

1. Short-term effects such as swelling were reported inconsistently.
2. Necrotizing of the tissue (tissue death) in the area, about 4%, was seen in large dogs at the age limit for the activity.

The [Alliance for Contraception in Cats and Dogs](http://www.acc-d.org/Esterilsol) has a [position paper](http://www.acc-d.org/ACCD%20docs/ZeuterinPPPPJan2014.pdf) on the subject. In summary, *possible* complications:

1. Testicular swelling and pain (short term).
2. Vomiting.
3. Necrosis or ulceration of the injection site.
4. Additional, localized, side effects as described in documentation.

Of note, and seems to be backed up by the comparison study initially linked (disclosure: found on the same site), the treatment has been used extensively for more than a decade with no long term side effects being reported. Given average lifespans of dogs, I think it's a long enough window to be called multi-generational.